# Muller TC 24.21 Timer Wiring Help

Tags: timer, wiring

A very basic question. I've just bought a digital time switch model TC 24.21 from Muller. According to the back of the timer it takes 230V~50-60Hz, and I'm a bit stuck exactly how and what to connect the timer up to to get it working.

All I'm trying to do at the moment is connect up the timer so the front turns on. I'll worry about the relay wiring once I've gotten that sorted.

Here is a picture of the back.

[image: Back of the timer]

I presume I need to connect the  L (live?) terminal to the positive terminal of the power source and the N (neutral?) terminal to the negative terminal of the power source, but I'm stuck with what power source to use? I can't safely plug it into mains power?

Datasheet is here: http://www.hugo-mueller.de/download/39_DB_TCx4_en.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datasheet clearly says "Supply Voltage 230 V, 50/60 Hz", so I would connect a 230 V "Hot' wire to the "L" terminal, and the neutral wire to the "N" terminal.  The timer would connect terminal 1 or 3 to L, depending on the state of the timer, so you would connect your 230 volt load between either 1 or 3 and N.

It appears that you can connect a switch between L and Ext to start/stop the timer.

With luck, there should be a more detailed user manual included with the timer.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I'm not sure how exactly to get a 230V 'Hot' wire without chopping up cables. I was hoping to plug the timer into a wall socket. Can I buy a component that is a plug on one end and splits into a 'neutral' and 'hot' wire on the other?

Comment: Yes. That component is called an "Extension Cord". You can cut it in half and one segment will have exactly what you need. You will need to separate and strip some insulation from the neutral, and hot wires. Should not be difficult. As a bonus, the other segment will have a connector of the opposite sex.

Comment: @BobT I'm aware I could use extension cord, however this is a project for work, and a prototype that needs to be repeated multiple times, so DIY won't really work. Does the only way to use the timer involve cutting up cables? I assumed given its an industrial timer, it would have a more 'proper' way of doing it?

Comment: Ah... Sorry about the flip answer. Yes, if your mains power is 230V, etc. you can use that. Without knowing more about how you intend to install it it's hard to make a suggestion. For instance, will it be mounted inside a chassis with 230V available somewhere within the enclosure. If so it may simply be a case of routing individual wires to the power source and the thing-to-be-switched. If not in an enclosure you will need to put it in its own box with the appropriate input and output connectors. Also consider a fuse of some sort in line with the switched power line.

Comment: In North America, you can buy AC line cords with a male 120 V plug on one end, and bare wires on the other.  I'd expect that similar cords would be available in other areas.  Otherwise, you could buy bulk AC cords and separate plugs, and assemble your own.

Comment: Thanks peter! After a bit of search I've found an New Zealand equivalent that should hopefully do the job. @BobT The installation is quite up in the air at the moment. Its to go on a bench with a wall socket on one end. I'm imagining that I'll mount the timer in a chassis and just run the line cord into the back and connect up the wires inside. I'll definitely look into a fuse as well. Thanks for both your help :)

Comment: Often, 90% of electrical work is actually mechanical.  This timer is made to be built into machinery, so you need to build a suitable enclosure, with line cord (with plug), and either a flush outlet, or a line cord (with socket).  All with code-legal strain relief.  Chopping an extension cord in half is a fine way to get those cords, just choose carefully so it is compatible with strain reliefs you can obtain, and so it doesn't look too tacky.